React show Login or Logout in Menu based on Login Token stored in Session
I need an help to show login or logout in header based on userdetails stored in the sessionstorage.
I tried all the possibilities still I am not able to fix it. I need to refresh the page inorder to show logout or hide logout on navigate
my appjs
function App() {
 
  return (
    <div className="App  ">
     <Headerr />

          <Routes>
     <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
     <Route path="/OTP" element={<OTP />} />
       <Route path="/Sidebar" element={< Sidebar/>} />
       <Route path="/Dashboard" element={< Dashboard/>} />
       <Route path="/Report" element={<Report />} />
       <Route path="/Headerr" element={<Headerr />} />
       <Route path="/Footer" element={<Footer />} />


       </Routes>
       <Footer />
      
    </div>
  );
}

function Headerr() {
  const { getDashboard,getEmail,logout} = AuthUser();
  const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState(getDashboard());
  const handleLogout = (e) => {
    logout();
  }
  return (
    <>
    <Row>
    <Navbar className="bg-body-tertiary navbar border border-1 border-gray navbar-expand navbar-light p-0 ">
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home"><img src={logo} alt="Logo" className='logo-width' /></Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle />
        <Navbar.Collapse className="justify-content-end">
          <Navbar.Text>
          {dashboard && (<><img src={icon} alt="icon" className='text-dark icon-width '/> <a href="#login" className='text-decoration-none'>{dashboard && dashboard.dealerName ? dashboard.dealerName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + dashboard.dealerName.slice(1):''}</a>  <FontAwesomeIcon style={{cursor:'pointer'}} onClick={handleLogout} icon={faSignOutAlt} className="text-dark fnt-wdth"/></>)}
          </Navbar.Text>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
    </Row>
    </>
  );
}

import axios from 'axios';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function AuthUser(){
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    function getToken (){
        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
        const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        return userToken;
    }

    function getEmail (){
        const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('email');
        const emailToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        return emailToken;
    }

    function getUser (){
        const userString = sessionStorage.getItem('user');
        const user_detail = JSON.parse(userString);
        return user_detail;
    }

    function getDashboard(){
        const dashboardString = sessionStorage.getItem('dashboard');
        const dashboard = JSON.parse(dashboardString);
        return dashboard;
    }


    const [token,setToken] = useState(getToken());
    const [user,setUser] = useState(getUser());
    const saveDashboard = (user) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('dashboard',JSON.stringify(user));
    }
    const saveToken = (user,email,token) =>{
        sessionStorage.setItem('token',JSON.stringify(token));
        sessionStorage.setItem('user',JSON.stringify(user));
        sessionStorage.setItem('email',JSON.stringify(email));

        setToken(token);
        setUser(user);

    }

    const logout = () => {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('email');
        sessionStorage.removeItem('dashboard');
        navigate('/');
    }

    const http = axios.create({
        baseURL:"http://localhost:8000/api",
        headers:{
            "Content-type" : "application/json",
            "Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    });
    return {
        setToken:saveToken,
        token,
        user,
        getToken,
        getEmail,
        getDashboard,
        http,
        logout,
        saveDashboard,
    }
}

After Login I navigate to dashboard but in header logout is not shown until I refresh the page
I need to refresh the page to view the logout button
Even after logout in the header logout does not disappear I need to refresh the page to disappear
